# Java ATM project logical error(s)

Tags: java, function, loops, logic, switch-statement

So here's my Source code :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ATM {

String names []= {"Nikhil", "Furrqaan", "Raj", "Saron", "Abishiek", "Aditya"};
static int pin_no;static int card_no;
static int card[]={1806978,1244668,5769124,7658301,6571354,5155499};
static int pin[]={4444, 3333, 2222, 1111, 6666, 7988};
int balance []={17867, 23345, 24670, 37532, 43637, 37356};
int account[]={219075286,156482798,456482748,465295772,665793758,565738957};
int f,ch,z;
static int r = 0;
static int opt=0;
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String args []) {
    int pincode=0;      
    int repeat=0;   
    ATM k=new ATM();
    do{
    k.info();
    k.login();
    for(int choice=0;choice<=5;choice++)
    if(card_no==card[choice] && pin_no==pin[choice]){
    k.menu(choice);
    break;
    }else{
    System.out.println("Wrong card no. or pincode");
    break;
    }
    k.End(repeat);
    }while(k.End(repeat)==0);

}

   void info(){
   Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd EEEEEEEEE',' yyyy ");
   SimpleDateFormat timeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" hh:mm:ss a");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("                  ****************************************************************       ");
   System.out.println("                  ***                         HSBC's  ATM                     ****       ");
   System.out.println("                  ****************************************************************       ");
   System.out.println("                  Date - "+ dateformatter.format(calender.getTime()));
   System.out.println("                  Time - "+timeformatter.format(calender.getTime()));
   System.out.println("                  ****************************************************************       ");
   System.out.println("");
   }

  void login (){
   System.out.println("                  >> Enter card number - ");
   card_no=s.nextInt();
   System.out.println("                  >> Enter pin number - ");
   pin_no= s.nextInt();
  }

void menu (int choice){
    System.out.println("                  Welcome "+names[choice]);
    System.out.println("                  Your Account no: is " + account[choice]);
    System.out.println("                  ###############################################        ");
    System.out.println("                  >>> [1]. Cash Withdrawal ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("                  >>> [2]. Fast Cash ");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("                  >>> [3]. Cash Deposit ");

     opt=s.nextInt();

    switch (opt){
    case 1:
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" dd'/'MM ");
        SimpleDateFormat timeformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm ");
        ATM k=new ATM();
        int ammount;
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  CASH WITHDRAWAL ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.print("                    Enter amount to withdraw - Rs.");
        ammount=s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        System.out.println("                  Please wait while we process your request...");

    if (ammount>balance[z]){
        System.out.println("                  You do not have sufficient balance in your account.");
        k.menu(choice);
        for(z=1;z<=1000000000;z++)
        System.out.print("\f");
    }else if (ammount>25000){
        System.out.println("                  The daily limit for cash withdrawal is Rs.25000 .");
        k.menu(choice);
    }else{
        balance[z]=balance[z]-ammount;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                  You have withdrawn Rs."+ammount+" from your account.");
        System.out.println("                  Please collect the cash.");
        System.out.println("                  Current Balance - Rs."+balance[z]);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
       }
        break; 
    case 2:
        int fast[]={100,500,1000,5000};
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  FAST CASH WITHDRAWAL ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  Please select a desired amount.");
        System.out.println("                  (1) Rs. 100 ");
        System.out.println("                  (2) Rs. 500 ");
        System.out.println("                  (3) Rs. 1000 ");
        System.out.println("                  (4) Rs. 5000 ");
        System.out.print("                     Your choice ? ");
        ch=s.nextInt();
        if (fast[ch-1]>balance[z])
        {
        System.out.println("                  You do not have sufficient balance in your account.");
        }else{
            switch(ch)
            {
            case 1:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            case 2:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            case 3:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            case 4:
            balance[z]=balance[z]-fast[ch-1];
            break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                  You have withdrawn Rs. "+fast[ch-1]+" from your account.");
        System.out.println("                  Please collect the cash.");
        System.out.println("                  Current Balance - Rs."+balance[z]);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  CASH DEPOSIT ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.print("                  Enter amount to deposit - Rs.");
        int deposite =s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        System.out.println("                  Please wait while we process your request...");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("                  You have deposited Rs."+deposite+" to your account.");
        System.out.println("                  The amount will be credited shortly.");
        System.out.println("                  Current Balance - Rs."+balance[z]+" + Rs."+deposite);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  BALANCE ENQUIRY ");
        System.out.println("                  ==========================  ");
        System.out.println("                  Account Number - "+card[z]);
        System.out.println("                  Available Balance - Rs."+balance[z]);
        System.out.println("                  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::");
        System.out.println("                  Please collect the reciept...");
  }
}
 int End(int repeat){
    ATM k=new ATM();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("                      What would you like to do next?           ");
    System.out.println("                      [1]. Enter main menu.                     ");
    System.out.println("                      [2]. Exit.                                ");
    int option=s.nextInt();
    switch (option){
    case 1:
        repeat=0;
        break;
    case 2:
        repeat=1;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please check input.");
    }
    return repeat;
   }
 }
```

When ever the only card number and pincode combination that works is the very first one. Everything else Prints the error message i.e "Wrong pincode or card number." And the last function of the program (void repeat) prints the "What would you like to do next?" part twice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: First? Do you mean that the only card/pin combination that works is the first in your array, or do you mean that if the user enters any valid combination first time it works and subsequently does not?

Comment: Wrong input method, you need the keyboard simulator.

Comment: I meant that only the first card/pin combination works @djna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment one line code **k.End(repeat);** above while condition and have a try. It will only display once then.

```
//k.End(repeat);
    } while (k.End(repeat) == 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the second problem. You are calling the End method twice. So no wonder it prints twice.

```
k.End(repeat);
}while(k.End(repeat)==0);
```

Now it works only for the first combination because you are breaking the loop in else part as well. So, it never checks for second value onwards

```
for(int choice=0;choice<=5;choice++)
if(card_no==card[choice] && pin_no==pin[choice]){
k.menu(choice);
break;
}else{
System.out.println("Wrong card no. or pincode");
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately see what's wrong here, but two more general observations:

1). Don't write all this and then start testing. Work in smaller pieces. Test the login() function, does it reliably return the two numbers entered by the user? Once you have confidence int that test the verifification of those two numbers against your array, and so on.

2). Use a debugger. Just stepping through your code and examining a few variables would quickly show you what's happening.

Comment: while these are very good suggestions, it won't help the user here. The problems are in the main method itself

Comment: @GV I don't agree. 1). surely debugging will help no matter where the code is? 2). By having confidence is what **does** work you can anlayse what must be broken. The analytic approach is key in larger problems.